# is there cv2 findcontours and boundingRect in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: opencv, keras, tensorflow2.0, contour

This is the same functionality as cv2.findContours and cv2.boundingRect, I tried googling and looking at tf.image.* but it doesn't seem to be implemented. Any advice? I like to do this in batch of binarized images and output bounding rectangles back with shape (batch_num, n_boxes, 4), the last dim corresponds to (x1, y1, x2, y2) of the boxes. Currently, I can accomplish this using cv2.findContours(...) follow by cv2.boundingRect(...) and with a for-loop if I have a batch of images. My goal is to have this done in pure tf (graph?) so it can be part of either training, or inference workflow. The performance is too slow if I can't integrate this in TF.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is meant for building computational graphs to represent a series of operations so that we eventually come up with a loss function.  We backprop on this loss function so we can minimise weights.  `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.boundingRect` are operations that cannot be parallelised on GPU due to the nature of the algorithms themselves.  Anything in `tf.image` can easily be represented as a computational graph.  Finding contours in an image cannot be done this way so naturally this functionality is not available.  You do not have a choice but to use a `for` loop but since this is done completely on CPU, you can perhaps use multiprocessing or threading to perform this on each image in parallel.